# Android, reference things in R.drawable. using variables?

Tags: android, android-resources

say I want to dynamically load an image file in `R.drawable.*` based on the value of a string

Is there a way to do this? It seems like I need to statically refer to anything in `R.`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you declared the id for the image in XML file? If you did, you can use the following method:

Let's say you have picture.png in your res/drawable folder.

In your activity, you can set your image resource in the main.xml file

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageId" android:src="@drawable/picture"></ImageView>
```

In FirstActivity

```
//to retrieve image using id set in xml.
String imageString = "imageId"
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageString , "id", "package.name");
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(resID);
```

imageString is the dynamic name. After which you can get the identifier of the dynamic resource.

Another method, you can do this:

```
//to retrieve image in res/drawable and set image in ImageView
String imageName = "picture"
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", "package.name");
ImageView image;
image.setImageResource(resID );
```

You will be able to reference your image resource and set your ImageView to it.

Comment: Thanks, for this method to work I would need to declare the image in the AndroidManifest.xml file, or is there another file? I wasn't able to find good info on this, but mabey im searching for the wrong thing

Comment: I have edited my example. Added 2 ways of retrieving the images. One is dynamically through the id in XML used for your activity. The other dynamically from the `res/drawable` folder. You do not need to declare images in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: need to rephrase.. One method is to dynamically retrieve the image. The other is to set the image. Not sure which one are you trying to do

Comment: Great response, really appreciate it! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 9):

```
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(drawablename, "drawable", getPackageName());
imageview.setImageResource(drawableId);
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: what if i have to choose the image from the folder depending upon the screen i.e. hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi??

Answer (score 1):

```
Class res = R.string.class;
Field field = res.getField("x" + pos);
headerId = field.getInt(null);
header.setText(headerId);
```

this works with drawables as well, just edit the string.  the header part is not required, it's just an example pulled from something I wrote a while ago.