# Loading image from XML-Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I have an xml file with different tag

```
<data>
   <name>xyz</name>
   <img> image with source(/res/img.jpg)</img>
   <desc>this is the description</desc>
</data>
```

I want to load the List of items available in the xml and on click of listitem i want to display name , image and description in a new screen.

Please help somebody .. its urgent..

Comment: Your urgency isn't our problem.

Comment: @S A did u achieved in loading the image from xml?

Answer (score 0):

There a number of tutorials on the web that describe how to tackle problems you are facing (XML/List on Android). Here are few:

- http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/05/listview-example-2-using-xml-resource-file/
- http://androidlistviews.blogspot.in/2012/02/simple-listview-using-xml-datasource.html
- http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

And there are many more on the web...

Comment: Hi guys i want that on first screen the super tags to be appeared in a list view and onclick of listitem, it shud go to a next screen displaying the description which is a nested tag in xml file

Comment: See: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 0):

Use this [**code example**](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/xml/dom/ParseDOMDocument.html) to `parse the XML` file first.

---

Then with the list of the images you will need to get image from `resource folder`.

To get image from `drawable` folder using its name [**use this code**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941304/android-reference-things-in-r-drawable-using-variables)

---

At last use [**this great tutorial**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) to display the bunch of images in arraylist.

---

Links are 1. http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/xml/dom/ParseDOMDocument.html
  2. [Android, reference things in R.drawable. using variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941304/android-reference-things-in-r-drawable-using-variables)
  3. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

When manged to  read the XML (if not tell me) here is the code i use to read imageNames out of an JSON to fill the ListView on the About activity:

```
holder.logo.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("about_logo_"+aboutItems.get(position).getID(),"drawable",getActivity().getPackageName()));
```

or you mean something else like saveing the binary into the xml and read it? then i must say that not what XML is made for!